Custom LoginController in Spring Security and post with Angular
Im trying to create my own LoginController so i can watch the data flow more closely, but either my post method is wrong or my controller is missing something.
Whenever I try to send a login request it skips my LoginController and goes straight to
UserDetailsService implementation as a blank String or Im getting that raw password cannot be null.
Code :
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    private final MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;a
    private final UserService userService;
    private final PasswordEncoderConfig passwordEncoder;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> loginUser(@RequestBody LoginDTO request){
            String unhashedPassword = request.getPassword();
            String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.passwordEncoder().encode(unhashedPassword);
            String username = request.getUsername();
            Optional<UserDTO> possibleUser = userService.getUserByNickNameAndPassword(username,hashedPassword);

        if (possibleUser.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(possibleUser.get());
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
    }
}

@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "PUT", "DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChainConfig(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors(corsConfigurationSource ->
                corsConfigurationSource.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .authorizeRequests(request ->
                request
                    .requestMatchers("/users/all").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/beers/propose").hasRole("USER")
                    .requestMatchers("/beer-updates/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/topic/beer-updates/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/beers/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(login -> {
                login.loginProcessingUrl("/login");
                login.successForwardUrl("/beers/all");
                login.failureUrl("/login");
            });

        return http.build();
    }
}

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<UserDTO> userDTO = userService.getUserByNickName(username);
        if(userDTO.isPresent()) {
            UserDTO foundUser = userDTO.get();
            return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                .withUsername(foundUser .getNickName())
                .password(foundUser .getPasswordHash())
                .roles((foundUser .getRole()))
                .build();
        }
        throw  new NoSuchElementException("nie ma takiego uzytkownika");
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    FormsModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login.component.css'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  username : string = ''
  password :string = ''
  loginURL = "http://localhost:8082/login";


  login() {
    const body = {nickName: this.username, unhashedPassword: this.password}
    this.http.post(this.loginURL, body).subscribe({
      next: login => {
        console.log("login successfuly ", login);
      },
      error: error => {
        console.error("login error ", error);
      },
      complete: () => {
        console.log("login completed");
      }
    })
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

}


Errors:
Angular
login.component.ts:27  
login error    
HttpErrorResponse {headers: \_HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: >  'OK', url: 'http://localhost:8082/login', ok: false, …}  
error  
{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '\<', "\<!DOCTYPE "... is not >  valid JSON at JSON.parse (\> \> \<anonymous\>…, text: ...  
headers  
\_HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit:ƒ}      
message  
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8082/login"  
name  
"HttpErrorResponse"  
ok  
false    
status  
200  
statusText  
"OK"  
url  
"http://localhost:8082/login"  
\[\[Prototype\]\]  
HttpResponseBase  

Spring
 Securing POST /login
2024-04-14T14:09:38.636+02:00 DEBUG 20800 --- [projektPiwo] [nio-8082-exec-1] .s.a.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher : No event was found for the exception org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
2024-04-14T14:09:38.637+02:00 ERROR 20800 --- [projektPiwo] [nio-8082-exec-1] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
 
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: nie ma takiego uzytkownika
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:118) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:133) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.lambda$authenticate$1(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:54) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:565) ~[micrometer-observation-1.12.4.jar:1.12.4]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.authenticate(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:53) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.wrapFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:240) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$AroundFilterObservation$SimpleAroundFilterObservation.lambda$wrap$0(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:323) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$ObservationFilter.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:224) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.ObservationFilterChainDecorator$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(ObservationFilterChainDecorator.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:195) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:230) ~[spring-security-config-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar:10.1.19]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: nie ma takiego uzytkownika
    at org.example.projektpiwo.security.MyUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(MyUserDetailsService.java:30) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:103) ~[spring-security-core-6.2.3.jar:6.2.3]
    ... 87 common frames omitted
 
2024-04-14T14:09:38.680+02:00 DEBUG 20800 --- [projektPiwo] [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to /login
2024-04-14T14:09:38.705+02:00 DEBUG 20800 --- [projektPiwo] [nio-8082-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login



Please add your code markdown formatted to the question. The majority of users willing to help won't open your pictures.  I surely don't. Also, how should anyone try to reproduce your problem when it's impossible to copy paste code? [ask]

And now the error log as well, just like you added the code. NEVER link question related stuff to external websites since links can get invalid - besides, why should people follow external links, that's just rude ;).

Spring Security's Form Login requires CSRF, mentioned here in the documentation.
Make sure you use CSRF when dealing with form login and thus don't disable it in the dedicated SecurityFilterChain:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChainConfig(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http

        // .csrf().disable() // <-- DON'T DISABLE !!!

        .cors(corsConfigurationSource ->
            corsConfigurationSource.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))

        .authorizeRequests(request ->
            request
                .requestMatchers("/users/all").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/beers/propose").hasRole("USER")
                .requestMatchers("/beer-updates/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/topic/beer-updates/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/beers/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())

        .formLogin(login -> {
            login.loginProcessingUrl("/login");
            login.successForwardUrl("/beers/all");
            login.failureUrl("/login");
        });

     return http.build();
}

Another approach would be to go with REST API and JWT.
